# remove class with formSubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsubmit

my error message below, with a highlighted field is working perfectly. Except now the powers that be want a different functionality.
Currently the error messaging highlights the field with a red border, and on focus the border is removed. However, now the powers that be want the red highlighting to persist until the user hits submit `onclick="return formSubmit()"`

I've tried using a .submit function (removing the unbind and remove focus from the .focus function, but the red highlighting persists regardless.

```
<!--Jquery function to override JS alert with DOM layer alert message-->
function customAlert(inputID,msg){
   var div = $(".errorPopup");
   div.css({"display":"block"});
   $("#"+inputID).addClass("CO_form_alert").parent().addClass("alertRed");
   if (div.length == 0) {
     div = $("<div class='errorPopup' onclick='$(this).hide();'></div>");
     $("body").prepend(div);
   } 
   div.html(msg);
   $("#"+inputID).focus(function(){
        $(this).unbind('focus'); // remove this handler
        $(this).removeClass("CO_form_alert")
               .parent().removeClass("alertRed"); // undo changes
        $('.errorPopup').hide(); // hide error popup
   });

}
```

Comment: Why you don't just remove the whole focus bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so narrow minded in my looking for a solution above - trying to tie the removeClass with the form submit (which had to many actions tied into it and would have been overly complicated).

Instead, I just did a remove class at the beginning of the error checking:

```
$("li").removeClass("alertRed");
$("input").removeClass("CO_form_alert");  
$("select").removeClass("CO_form_alert");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you. If not please tell me, but can't you just do:

```
$('.theform').submit(function() {

  $('input', this).removeClass('CO_form_alert').parent().removeClass('alertRed');
  $('.errorPopup').hide();    

  return false;
});
```

Why do you need to unbind?

Comment: unfortunately, the above is not working. The popup is not hiding, and the alertRed class is persisting

Comment: Can you please post the relevant HTML?